# How to add data into a JFree XY chart every 5 seconds?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

[image: How the graph currently looks like]

I have access to a database that returns the temperature of a location and time of that location every 5 seconds.
I have an idea of plotting the time on the x-axis.
And probably by using the java swing timer I would be able to add data into the graph every 5 seconds.
However, I do not know how to implement that because I thought of adding a  timer in createDataset( ) but since it returns a dataset, I won't be able to achieve it.
Any idea how I would be able to add data into the graph every 5 seconds?
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.BasicStroke; 

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel; 
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart; 
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset; 
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries; 
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame; 
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities; 
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot; 
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory; 
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation; 
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection; 
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;

public class XYLineChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame {

public XYLineChart_AWT( String applicationTitle, String chartTitle ) {
  super(applicationTitle);
  JFreeChart xylineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
     chartTitle ,
     "Time" ,
     "Temperature" ,
     createDataset() ,
     PlotOrientation.VERTICAL ,
     true , true , false);

  ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel( xylineChart );
  chartPanel.setPreferredSize( new java.awt.Dimension( 560 , 367 ) );
  final XYPlot plot = xylineChart.getXYPlot( );

  XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer( );
  renderer.setSeriesPaint( 0 , Color.RED );
  renderer.setSeriesStroke( 0 , new BasicStroke( 4.0f ) );
  plot.setRenderer( renderer ); 
  setContentPane( chartPanel ); 
}

private XYDataset createDataset( ) {
  final XYSeries temp = new XYSeries( "Temperature" );  
  //time = getTime(); //returns a float time in seconds.milliseconds
  //temperature = getTemp(); //returns a number temperature 
  //I want to add data into temp every 5 seconds but i don't know how to do it        
  temp.add( 1.0 , 1.0 );          
  temp.add( 2.0 , 4.0 );          
  temp.add( 3.0 , 3.0 );                  

  final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection( );          
  dataset.addSeries( temp );
  return dataset;
}

public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
  XYLineChart_AWT chart = new XYLineChart_AWT("Temp",
     "Temperature of some location");
  chart.pack( );          
  RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chart );          
  chart.setVisible( true ); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting a timer in your `createDataset()` method you can instead spawn a new thread from your main method that modifies your JFreeChart dataset every 5 seconds.

For example you could do it something like this:

```
public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
  XYLineChart_AWT chart = new XYLineChart_AWT("Temp",
     "Temperature of some location");
  chart.pack( );          
  RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chart );          
  chart.setVisible( true ); 

  //now make your timer
  int delay = 5000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //some code here to get and modify your dataset so it can be updated
          // ----
          // ----
          //now apply your new dataset to your JFreeChart
          xylineChart.getXYPlot().setDataset(myNewDataset);
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, timerAction).start();
}
```

Remember to add some code to remove old entries in your dataset so that the chart remains readable and all the values on the Time axis remain the same distance apart between different datasets, for example make sure there are no more than 24 items (2 minutes of data) plotted at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm new to JFree charts so when I try to use the exact code you wrote above,  it gives me errors.  http://i.imgur.com/hLxz3wg.png

Comment: You could also `add()` an item to the `XYSeries` in your `XYSeriesCollection`.

Comment: Ok, I changed my code, however, it doesn't add to the chart but instead refreshes the chart. So the chart contains only 1 plot at a time.    
https://pastebin.com/pfd2RY5r      
Instead of re-making the chart every 5 seconds, how do I 'append' to it instead?

Comment: That is best asked as a new question, but one way to do it would be to keep a persistent `XYSeriesCollection myNewDataset` that can be accessed class wide that you only create once at the start. Then you can remove `final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection( );` and instead just use `dataset.addSeries( temp );` in your update method, that way it always has all previous data, and you only add to it each time instead of making a new dataset each time.